# Unable to view the add screen in Django's Admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I added a field to my database model that was completely unrelated, when I started getting this issue

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/backend/network/add/

Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['backend.apps.BackendConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 19
   'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  194.                 return template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  177.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  211.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  314.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  999.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_value_in_context
  978.             value = str(value)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  380.     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in __str__
  36.         return self.as_widget()

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in as_widget
  118.             **kwargs

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
  234.         context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py" in get_context
  104.         context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in get_context
  808.             value = self.decompress(value)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in decompress
  896.             value = to_current_timezone(value)

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\utils.py" in to_current_timezone
  176.     if settings.USE_TZ and value is not None and timezone.is_aware(value):

File "C:\Users\woode\Documents\RIoT Suite\riot-portal\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py" in is_aware
  247.     return value.utcoffset() is not None

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/backend/network/add/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

I can view my pages and the all of the administrative panel just fine with the exception of the add page where this error occurs, and the users and groups models work without issue. Does anyone have a fix? I literally just hit my head on the desk with this one.

Comment: Did you run your migrations?

Comment: I thought so, but then I just tried running migrate again and it says it has operations to preform but doesnt run them. When I run makemigrations nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post your models.py?

Comment: My models.py is large and Id rather not share the entire thing publically but this is the part I edited brfore the issue-

Comment: `class Notification(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default='django.contrib.timezone.now')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    positive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`

Comment: Which was the field that you added? Check your migrations files to ensure that the field was added. Also next time you can post your code by editing your question

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Django on one of their pages and in the source code itself recommends `'django.util.timezone.now'` however, this was causing the issue and I simply changed it to a `datetime.now()` Weird issue... it worked for a while with the django timezone.